# Spark Dataframe query syntax Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to make the following Dataframe query work in Java but its not giving me the results. (The desired result is in the details below) Can someone please help?

Is there a reference guide to see all the syntax to create dataframe queries? Here this is what I want - My dataframe df has many cols among which 4 are -

1. id
2. deviceFlag
3. device
4. domain

**This is the result I need** - For all rows, if deviceFlag is set to 1, then form a string "device#domain" and store that value in a new col "id". Else, just take the value in the "device" col and store it in the new  "id" col without any transformation. So I am creating a new column with the .withColumn and setting value for each row depending upon the corresponding values of "device" and "deviceFlag" cols in that row.

```
DataFrame result= df.withColumn("id",
    ((Column) when(df.col("deviceFlag").$eq$eq$eq(1),
        concat(df.col("device"), lit("#"),
            df.col("domain")))).otherwise(df.col("device")).alias("id"));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added more details and edited post. Added desired results info too